# Адаптивная ширина видео

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Сайт на bootstrap, на сайте много видео с разной шириной, при просмотре на мобильных вылазит за границу экрана, ставлю width:100%, на мобильном ОК, а на ПК все видео на всю ширину div. Как сделать что бы ширина каждого видео не превышала его исходной ширины?

```css
.text_content_res{margin-top:5px;}
video{display:inline-block;margin: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="row text_content_res ">
  <video class="" id='gifid' onclick='playPause(this.id)' loop>
    <source src='https://test.reseto.com/gifs/3e0d796625761fb1967746649011d2ce.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
  </video>
  <div class="play_button" id='gifidpause' onclick='playPause("gifid")'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.text_content_res{
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 }
video{
 display:inline-block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row text_content_res ">
  <video class="" id='gifid' onclick='playPause(this.id)' loop>
    <source src='https://test.reseto.com/gifs/3e0d796625761fb1967746649011d2ce.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
  </video>
  <div class="play_button" id='gifidpause' onclick='playPause("gifid")'></div>
</div>
```

Позиционирование нужно не забывать, и ширина в процентах + max-width, вот и все

Comment: Спасибо. Вроди бы получилось :)

Comment: Используйте сочетание width:100% & max-width